# How "low" does C go as a "low-level" language?

Tags: c, programming-languages, low-level

We often hear that C is a low-level language, but how low does it go? The lowest level I am aware of is memory management using pointers. Are there further levels I have yet to discover? What does "close to the hardware" mean? How "close to the hardware" is C?

Comment: "The C Programming Language — A language which combines the flexibility of assembly language with the power of assembly language."

Comment: @jason http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html

Comment: C hit me with a segfault, gave me no error reporting, and then laughed in my face. I thought that was pretty low :(

Comment: Yes @jason, in the middle of your C code, you can switch to assembly for when you want to squeeze that last bit of performance.

Comment: @glowcoder- Aren't segfaults run-time errors ?

Comment: @ecounysis Sometimes broader questions get marked that way... at the moment, there's a "reopen" vote going on, and I expect your question will reopen. It may be a bit of a roller coaster, but you'll get input!

Comment: @ecounysis Higher level typically means less need to know about the hardware.  A file system is higher level than a hard disk controller.  A set of command line tools like cp (copy), ls (dir), etc. is higher level than a file system.  A graphical desktop file manager (like nautilus / midnight commander / explorer) is higher level than a set of command line tools.  The lowest level is direct hardware interfacing, because it doesn't represent any "higher level" abstraction of the hardware: it is the hardware.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the standard terminology.  Higher level languages and Lower level languages.

High level languages are designed for the ease of the person writing the language.

Lower level languages are designed for the ease of the computer running the language.

C is just a step up from assembly language, which is practically a human translation of machine code.  It doesn't get any lower than machine code, but people don't read hexadecimal very well, so assembly is considered the lowest level programming language.

Most C operations can be translated into less than ten machine instructions.  Some can be translated into a single machine instruction (depending on many circumstances).  By comparison, many high-level languages might require dozens to thousands of machine instructions to implement a particular operation.

The "level" of a language is mostly an abstract concept.  It is not useful for much except comparing one language to another in the context of trying to understand if you will have to write more source code in one or another, or if you will have to know more about the machine's architecture in one language as compared to another.

Comment: Linus started out coding in *"machine code"/raw instructions*. Wasn't until later on he realized there was something called assembly language ;)

Answer (score 6):

C is little more than a procedural wrapper around ASM. A good C programmer, who knows what's behind that language, should be able to look at a code snippet and write out the ASM that the code would compile into. Those ASM instructions can be translated 1:1 to binary machine instructions. It's pretty much one step above assembly, and as such you can write C code that does ANYTHING the computer is capable of, BUT, being at such a low level, it is relatively primitive in terms of what you have to be specific about. For instance, memory is treated as such, and not abstracted into constructs like the "heap". Creating a "new" object in an OO language is as simple as saying so; the equivalent C code would involve a malloc for the sum of the size of all the members of that object, and pointers to each of the object's members within the block.

Comment: If you stick to the computation part of ASM, yes.  What C can't do is what the rest of ASM does:  Setting machine state (try loading ESP on an X86 from pure C), configuring the hardware (devices, interrupt levels, memory management) and actual device I/O, managing tasks (context switching, interrupts).  So C is low level, but Pascal wasn't a lot different.  C isn't bare metal.

Comment: ...assuming they know the assembly language for the target platform they're working on.

Comment: C can't do tail recursion. See C minus minus

Comment: No. A good C programmer knows how to write good C code and - if needed - write portable C. There's *really* no need for a good C programmer to be very good or even good in any given assembly language. It requires knowledge of not C, but rather the innards of your compiler to guess how it will compile any not-very-basic code snippet.

Comment: @user606723: Of course it can. Nothing in the standard prohibits that, and if fact tail call optimization was one of the earliest 'optimizations' of an optimizing compiler.

Comment: "write out the ASM that the code would compile into" ... by a simplistic compiler with all optimization disabled. What a decent compiler will actually produce might not be related to this "first cut" in any obvious way.

Answer (score 6):

C is sometimes referred to as "portable assembly language".  Essentially anything that you can do in assembly, you can do in C (either through features built into the language or through inline assembly).

Comment: Of course, inline assembly is not part of the C language.

Comment: @eq- True, the `asm` keyword is not officially a part of the standard (it's only listed as a "common extension").  Virtually every compiler supports some form of inline assembly, however.  If you can get a pointer to the address space where your code resides, you can write self-modifying code that injects arbitrary assembly commands (at run-time) using standard C-language constructs.

Comment: @eq- If you can get such a pointer, you can do all that from any language that has pointers, e.g., Pascal.   I used to do this with the POKE command on TRS80 computers in BASIC.

Comment: I think Ira meant @bta. QEMU is actually a really interesting project for this discussion; it's a dynamic recompiling emulator that is written without dependencies on the target architecture. It achieves that through global variables, C functions to perform the emulated instructions and navigating from function pointers to the actual code inside the function such as to grab the compiled stuff at runtime and stitch it together. So it makes assumptions beyond the C spec and hence isn't technically valid C, but works in practise across a range of machines and compilers.

Comment: @eq- The technique can differ on different architectures.  See http://www.thedarkalliance.org/cc/self-modifying-c-code/ for an example.

Comment: @eq:  Tommy is right, I meant the pointer that @bta "referenced" :-}

Answer (score 4):

A person who creates hardware (cpu, motherboard, etc) also provide its machine language (assembly language). That becomes the lowest level itself. Then some other person writes a compiler for C which converts C syntax into native assembly language for that hardware (please correct me if I am wrong). With C you can use assembly hence lowest level reached!!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of 'low' is a bit difficult, but C supports an number of system calls, gotos, and even assembly mixing through extensions.

Comment: Extensions to the C language may support 'mixing assembly'.

Comment: @eq Good point, updated.

Comment: I have access to the C99 draft only, but the 'asm' keyword is defined in J.5.10 with "The asm keyword may be used to insert assembly language directly into the translator
output (6.8). The most common implementation is via a statement of the form: asm( character-string-literal );". So just supporting assembly isn't technically an extension; how you support assembly is.

Comment: @Tommy- Note that section J.5 is named "common extensions".  These aren't mandatory features.  It's available in nearly every C compiler out there, but technically it's still a compiler extension.

Comment: @bta it has become clear that I'm a poor reader. Please treat my comment as if it had been deleted (but it hasn't, since then it won't be clear what you're talking about in response)

Answer (score 2):

The memory you can manage on general purpose OS' are usually [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), so it usually all a fraud - your C pointers doesn't contain the physical memory addresses, there's a whole layer deeper than that.

Getting below that requires you to program the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) , which isn't easily done in C, it usually requires some very architecture dependant assembly and your code would need to run in some form of privileged [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes)(as the OS kernel does)

There might also be various other [co-processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion_Engine#Vector_processing_units) or whole range of [instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE3) it can be hard to get at directly in C.

Comment: But that is true if you're writing a program in assembly or even machine code that runs in the user space of a modern OS. It is not peculiar to any language where you manually manage memory. For simple systems with flat memory and no concept of virtual memory you can use C to access memory addresses directly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define what you mean by *low level* in order to answer this question.

C lets you do kind of everything you could do with assembly, but well not everything. If you want to do something weird/particular/unusual you could need to use assembly, although for most(/all?) real purposes C will be more then enough, assuming you've got a good compiler for your hardware.

---

**EDIT**: Elaborating this a little further...

C doesn't give you any guarantee about the assembly instruction it will be compiled into, and only gives some partial indications about objects will be allocated in memory.

In general If you need to have stuff in memory in a particular way, of if you need a particular sequence of assembly instruction to be ran, you'll probably have to use some other language (probably assembly directly), otherwise **in general** C will be fine.

Of course we can find as many special cases as we want to: if your has got some special assembly operations that let you do fancy *high level* stuff, C won't probably be able to exploit these.

C has been thought to replace assembly on *normal* (maybe I could say *general purpose*) processors, it won't be ideal on processors with a native functional assembly or in many other contexts.

---

You cannot just say "how level is C?", you need to do the opposite: define what kind of *low level* stuff you need and then see if C is able to do that.

Comment: What I mean by low level is what everybody means when they say C is a low-level language. If I knew that I wouldn't have to ask the question.

Comment: @ecounysis: my point is that there's no standard definition for _low level_. If you want to generate a specific sequence of assembly instruction C won't be able to do that. If you want to implement a real world algorithm C will be perfect.

Comment: (@who_downvoted: could you explain, please?)

Comment: +1 for counter-voting, as this answer is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

How about `register`? A keyword on a local variable declaration that asks the compiler to store it in a CPU register - though it may ignore your suggestion.

However, GNU C extends this to the point where you can specify a particular register you'd like to use!

```
register int foo asm ("a5");
```

Comment: Per the (draft) C99 spec, "A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined". GCC extensions aside, I guess the main concern would be where you'd like access to a special-purpose register that doesn't map to a C type? The status register is a common and obvious but not very useful one; your hardware may have others.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that C obscures, to the extent that it obscures anything at all, is flow control, in a few edge cases. The only thing I've ever written in assembly that didn't translate well to C involved hopping into a block of code at an arbitrary point, having it execute from that position, periodically checking a certain status condition and upon finding the need, storing the current program location somewhere and exiting. Then next time, I jumped back in at the same position as that block of code last exited. Co-operative coroutines, I guess you'd call them.

The C solution was to use two separate threads, communicating via semaphores. But threads aren't part of the C language itself.

Answer (score 1):

C today is used in many cases as a "portable assembly language" because the semantics of the language can be pretty much just a thin veneer above the underlying machine architecture.

In the past, it was fairly straight forward to look at lines of C code and have a good idea what the actual machine language would be that the C code would generate.

When taken in it entirety along with its surrounding development environment, it is straightforward to have perfect control over memory layout of data structures and overall memory placement. Mind, this kind of C code is, as a whole, non portable as it relies on implementations details of the compiler that the C standard allows to be flexible and implementation based. But in the large, the C code itself can be MOSTLY portable. This is aspect of the language is what led to its popularity in such systems as Unix in allowing the bulk of the OS to be portable across machines with as little implementation specific aspects of an implementation being in, say, assembly language, as possible.

Today, with modern compilers and their optimizations, C can be less literal. What you see in the C code may not be translated literally in to what you get in the assembly because of the actual optimizations made by the compiler.

A simple contrived example is something like:

```
int func(int a, int b) {
    int c;
    int d;

    d = 10;
    return a * d;
}
```

In a simple compiler, an implementation may well allocate 4 int's on the stack, 2 for the arguments, and 2 for the work variables. An obvious optimization is to not allocate the 'c' variable at all, as it is unused. A further optimization is to ignore 'd' as well, and simply use the constant 10. And even smarter compiler may well see how this func is being used and inline it automatically in the calling function, eliminating the subroutine call completely.

So, on the one hand you can see the code and say "this is what it will look like in assembly", and thus treat it as a low level wrapper on top of assembly. On the other, you can turn the modern compilers optimizations up so that they are less literal, thus keeping the semantics of what you're expressing in code, if not the actual perfect implementation.

Answer (score 1):

What I mean by low level is what everybody means when they say C is a low-level language. If I knew that I wouldn't have to ask the question. – ecounysis 27 secs ago

Thats not what the question looked like at all.

If what you want to know is what "low-level" means when they say that, wiki has articles you may want to read.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language

When they say C is a low-level language they aren't talking about any degree. Either a language is higher level or low level. They are two different types or Categories.

Comment: What does "close to the hardware" mean? I think that is what I am trying to get at with my question. Also, how "close to the hardware" is C?

Comment: From the horse's mouth: "[BCPL, B, and C] are 'close to the machine' in that the abstractions they introduce are readily grounded in the concrete data types and operations supplied by conventional computers, and they rely on library routines for input-output and other interactions with an operating system."  - from http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html.  For example, an `int` in C maps closely to a native word on the underlying platform, and thus has similar limits in range and precision.  Compare with a language like Haskell, where numeric types can have arbitrary precision.

Answer (score -4):

The fact that you ask this question expresses your naivete of the subject.
It's just not that simple.

In the end-
**C does not have the complete flexibly of a assembly language, but it comes close.
It's missing features such as Tail Recursion**

But for most purposes, C does everything you would -probably need-

Comment: You're right. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: My point is that you should probably do a bit more reading before asking a question like this... It's something a book could be written about...

Comment: I read books all the time and I've never seen this question answered.

Comment: this is why I don't ask questions on stackoverflow anymore. People don't care about helping your or answering your question, they just want to solve the harder problems for points. Anything other than that and they tell you to piss off and read a book